# Unit test with xunit and mock for Web API in c# - Put method not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

I have the below code in test project which always fails while trying to do Unit test. But the same method works from the front end

```
public void UpdateGroup()
{
    var group = new Group()
    {
        GroupName = "Grp",
        Capacity = 40
    };

    //Valid Input Id
    mock.Setup(p => p.UpdateGroup(6, group));
    GroupsController grp = new GroupsController(mock.Object);
    var result = grp.PutGroup(6, group);
    Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
}
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult PutGroup([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Group group)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    try
    {
        var grp = _groupsService.GetGroupById(id);

        if (grp == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            _groupsService.UpdateGroup(id, group);
            return Ok(group);
        }
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!GroupExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }           
}
```

I know the error is on `_groupsService.GetGroupById(id);` which always returns `null` in unit test.

What needs to changed or added in unit test code to make it work?

Comment: I think you have to mock _groupsService too

Comment: mock in test project code is public Mock<IGroupsService> mock = new Mock<IGroupsService>(); @GHDevOps

Comment: you need to set up for the mock also for GetGroupById `mock.Setup(p => p.GetGroupById(6)).Returns(something);`